# avoid opening mail.php on submit

Tags: php, html

When the submit button is clicked, how do I avoid the browser opening my1.php file?

```
   <form action="mail/my1.php" method="POST">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
           </form>
```

Comment: you can submit this in a iframe. see answer

Comment: You could do it using Ajax

Comment: What should the form do after clicking on submit?

Comment: @Mario: I want to open the thankyou.html  I want to also disable the browser back button. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to register the name into a table then redirect to the thankyou.html page?

Comment: Mario Johnathan's comments appear to be the only sane ones here.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use the iframe, use the `header` function to redirect the user ... he will be redirected to my1.php and then thrown to another page, he wont even recognize it. And if you dont use `exit;` after the header, the script will still be executed.

```
header("location: anotherpage.php");
```

iFrame solution is cleaner and better. I just want to offer you another possibility. Especially because the html-markup can be modified which makes your website vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks Y U NO WORK. Is it required to add an  exit(); at the end? What does this exit(); mean here?

Comment: The `exit` is optional. Its usually used for aborting a script during runtime. In your case, you want the script to run, so you shouldnt use it. For more information about `exit` or `die`, you can look into the php documentary http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of options, here there are ordered by personal preference:

1. Add a PHP redirect with [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in `mail/my1.php`
2. Use [AJAX, jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) makes it rather convenient
3. Use a frame or an iframe*, not my favorite

* Nothing to do with Apple.

Comment: Thanks Nabil for bringing all those options to the table. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can submit your page in iframe if you don't want to go on submit page as below

```
   <form action="mail/my1.php" method="POST" target="my_iframe">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name"><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

    <iframe id="myiframe" name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

The above will submit you form in iframe.

**UPDATE 2:**

if you don't want to submit the page and do other things like JS/Jquery submit you can simply add `onsubmit="return false"` in you from tag

```
<form action="mail/my1.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_form">
 </form>
```

**UPDATE 3:**

if you want to disable your button after click on submit button use this js function

```
document.getElementsById("submit_form").onclick = function () {
    this.disabled = true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Sharma. But the user might click the submit button multiple times. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score -1):

remove the action  from the form tag. The data will not get redirected. If you still want to fetch the values on post use $_REQUEST  or $_POST to get values on submit.

YOu can do it as :

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
   $a=$_REQUEST['name'];
}
```